# spread syntax in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

Is it possible to "spread" array elements in c# so that I can pass them to another function?

For example, in Javascript, we can do

```
function myFunction(x, y, z) { }
var args = [0, 1, 2];
myFunction(...args);
```

Is there a similar functionality in c#? The reason I want to do this is that I have a SQL statement with a lot of columns and I want to instantiate a new object with each row without having to explicitly set each field to a particular column. I can use `reader.GetValues` to get an array of all my column values, but can I use this to conveniently create objects?

Comment: With C# 6 or newer with it's new ValueTuples you can. However I would reccomend switching to a lightweight ORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) (it is the library that stack overflow uses to run it's own website)

Comment: You might also want to look at the [`params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) keyword that allows you to pass an array or a set of separate variables/constants.  Though that's some that has to be part of the method definition and all the values would have to be the same type.

Comment: Also for mapping SQL to objects you might want to look at [`Dapper`](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).  It simplifies a lot of ADO.Net code to allow you map the results to objects.

Comment: If that doesn't answer your question, [edit] to explain why `params` won't work.